# Extracting a list of values from a list of maybes without fromJust

Tags: haskell

Input: `[Just "foo", Just "bar", Nothing, Just "quux"]`

Output: `["foo", "bar", "quux"]`

I'm not satisfied with the following solution using `fromJust` because it's not very portable to *elm* which doesn't like unsafe functions:

`extract list = map fromJust $ filter isJust list`

Is there another concise / idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: For pepole looking for the elm translation, this can be achieved with `List.filterMap identity`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `catMaybes`:

```
import Data.Maybe
catMaybes list
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Λ: :m + Data.Maybe
Λ: concatMap maybeToList [Just "foo", Just "bar", Nothing, Just "quux"]
["foo","bar","quux"]
```